# Write metadata for image in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, metadata

I am developing an app that allows a user to fill metadata to an image from UI like:

- Name
- Location
- Maker Notes
- ....

Is there any way to do it in Flutter?

You can check by http://metapicz.com/#landing with any image URL

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot updated questions

Comment: have you managed to find any solutions? I have the same problem as you...

Comment: @akajack not yet

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I could not find a way to edit EXIF metadata of images too...

Comment: I see a deleted answer referring https://github.com/naung9/flutter_exif_rw however it seems the last update was 2 years ago so not sure if this is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need mobile support, there's a [new package](https://pub.dev/packages/native_exif) that can do this for you.

You add it as a dependency and then...

```dart
final exif = await Exif.fromPath(file.path);
final attributes = await exif!.getAttributes();
attributes['UserComment'] = "This file was edited by FlutterApp!";
final result = await exif.writeAttributes(attributes);
```

Comment: Where does the 'newExif' come from in the example?

Comment: @VladH It was just a naming error.

Comment: I have used this code, but I am not able to write data?

Comment: @Ram My code example is from over a year ago, and the package has been updated since. Better have a look at their code examples, or open a ticket on the repo, if you encounter an issue with the package.